# detecting invalid iterators for a ring buffer

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

I'm trying to implement a ring buffer (or circular buffer). As with most of these implementations it should be as fast and lightweight as possible but still provide enough safety to be robust enough for production use. This is a difficult balance to strike. In particular I'm faced with the following problem.

I want to use said buffer to store the last n system events. As new events come in the oldest get deleted. Other parts of my software can then access those stored events and process them at their own pace. Some systems might consume events almost as fast as they arrive, others may only check sporadically. Each system would store an iterator into the buffer so that they know where they left off last time they checked. This is no problem as long they check often enough but especially the slower systems may oftentimes find themselves with an old iterator that points to a buffer element that has since been overwritten without a way to detect that.

Is there a good (not too costly) way of checking whether any given iterator is still valid?

Things I came up with so far:

- keep a list of all iterators and store their valid state (rather costly)
- store not only the iterator in the calling systems but also a copy of the pointed-to element in the client of the buffer. On each access, check whether the element is still the same. This can be unreliable. If the element has been overwritten by an identical element it is impossible to check whether it has changed or not. Also, the responsibility of finding a good way to check elements lies with the client, which is not ideal in my mind.

Many ring buffer implementations don't bother with this at all or use a single-read-single-write idiom, where reading is deleting.

Comment: How many consumers do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with [Roger Lipscombe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26361959/1390164), use sequence numbers.

But you don't need to store (value, sequence_num) pairs: just store the values, and keep track of the highest sequence number so far. Since it's a ring buffer, you can deduce the seq num for all entries.

Thus, the iterators consist simply of a sequence number.

Given `Obj` the type of object you store in your ring buffer, if you use a simple array, your ring buffer would look like this:

```
struct RingBuffer {
    Obj buf[ RINGBUFFER_SIZE ] ;
    size_t idx_last_element ;
    uint32_t seqnum_last_element ;

    void Append( const Obj& obj ) { // TODO: Locking needed if multithreaded 
        if ( idx_last_element == RINGBUFFER_SIZE - 1 )
            idx_last_element = 0 ; 
        else 
            ++idx_last_element ;
        buf[ idx_last_element ] = obj ; // copy.
        ++ seqnum_last_element ;
    }
}
```

And the iterator would look like this:

```
struct RingBufferIterator {
    const RingBuffer* ringbuf ;
    uint32_t seqnum ;

    bool IsValid() { 
        return ringbuf && 
               seqnum <= ringbuf->seqnum_last_element &&
               seqnum > ringbuf->seqnum_last_element - RINGBUFFER_SIZE ; //TODO: handle seqnum rollover.
    }

    Obj* ToPointer() {
         if ( ! IsValid() ) return NULL ;
         size_t idx = ringbuf->idx_last_element - (ringbuf->seqnum_last_element-seqnum) ; //TODO: handle seqnum rollover.
         // handle wrap around:
         if ( idx < 0 ) return ringbuf->buf + RINGBUFFER_SIZE- idx ;
         return ringbuf->buf + idx ;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of storing values, store `(value, sequence_num)` pairs. When you push a new `value`, always make sure that it uses a different `sequence_num`. You can use a monotonically increasing integer for `sequence_num`.

Then, the iterator remembers the `sequence_num` of the element that it was last looking at. If it doesn't match, it's been overwritten.

Comment: I'd use terminology like "sequence number" instead of "age" for this, but +1 in any case.

Comment: Your suggestion is better; I renamed 'age' to 'sequence_num'. Thanks.

Comment: or better yet : the iterator IS the sequence number. Then your buffer just needs to keep track of the lowest sequence number it currently holds, and which position it's in.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker, that's a good suggestion; you should expand on it in a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

A variation of [Roger Lipscombe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26361959#822669), is to use a sequence number as the iterator. The sequence number should be monotonically increasing (take special care of when your integer type overflows) with a fixed step (1 eg.).

The circular buffer itself would store the data as normal, and would keep track of the oldest sequence number it currently contains (at the tail position).

When dereferencing the iterator, the iterator's sequence number is checked against the buffer's oldest sequence number. If it's bigger or equal (again take special care of integer overflow), the data can be retrieved using a simple index calculation. If it's smaller, it means the data has been overwritten, and the current tail data should be retrieved instead (updating the iterator's sequence number accordingly).